# How to add Bluetooth pairing functionality in react native app for android and iOS ? Any library or links?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want to implement bluetooth functionality into my react native app for android and iOS which adds bluetooth paring and transfer the text files between devices.

Any library, documents or related links which helps to implement the functionality in react native app?

Answer (score 0):

This could be best fit for your requirement.
https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx